# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snorkel.labeling'

Tags: python, jupyter, snorkel

I installed snorkel using conda and when I try to run -  `from snorkel.labeling import labeling_function` it throws the following error - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snorkel.labeling'`.

I tried looking up for a solution on Github, but unfortunately, I couldn't follow through. I have also tried installing `nb_conda_kernels`, to make all your conda environments available in jupyterbut it didn't help. Also tried creating a separate env, installing snorkel and launching jupyter notebook from the snorkel's environment, and it didn't work either. Any form of help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try [these install instructions](https://github.com/snorkel-team/snorkel/issues/1412#issuecomment-522163781):

```
conda create --yes -n snorkel
conda activate snorkel
conda install pytorch==1.1.0 -c pytorch
conda install snorkel==0.9.0 -c conda-forge
```

## Or these, [listed here](https://github.com/snorkel-team/snorkel-tutorials#-installing-yourself-):

```
# [OPTIONAL] Activate a virtual environment
conda create --yes -n spam python=3.6
conda activate spam

# Install requirements (both shared and tutorial-specific)
pip install environment_kernels
# We specify PyTorch here to ensure compatibility, but it may not be necessary.
conda install pytorch==1.1.0 -c pytorch
conda install snorkel==0.9.5 -c conda-forge
pip install -r spam/requirements.txt

# Launch the Jupyter notebook interface
jupyter notebook spam
```

Comment: I followed all the above steps and only after mapping notebook's env to snorkel's, I could fix it. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following:

## For pip users

`pip install snorkel`

## For conda users

`conda install snorkel -c conda-forge`